# change the hero's appearance using spritekit and objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode

is it possible, and if it is, then how can I change heros appearance in game. What I want to do, is making something like options, were user can choose what hero looks like. Here are my plan for my project [image]

Options should look something like this:
[image]
I made separate file only for hero node, for hero appearance I use this basic code:

```
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {

    self = [HeroNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed: @"heroOne.png"];
    self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    self.name = name;
    self.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:self.frame.size];
   // there are more, but I think it does not matter to this issue
```

Im not a strong at this, so please go easy on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could answer in more details how to do exactly what you want to. But as far as it is described you want to change only the spriteTexture of your hero ( to give a change skin effect). On the hero sprite node ( and any other SKSpriteNode is possible to change only the **TEXTURE**, to do so you must do something like:

`[self setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"heroNewSkin.png"]];`

This should change the texture ( appearance) of your hero on the fly. Remember that the image should be imported into your Xcode project. And the image should be the same size as the previous one, if not you should change the size property of you hero `SKSpriteNode`.

To know more about it a good reference sprite-kit tutorials source is  - https://www.raywenderlich.com

Comment: thank you for your response and yes I want to only change texture of hero, I look up to the website you post.

Comment: No problem, if it helped you to solve the problem, please mark as "accepted answer" ;). Also if you have any questions, i have quite experience on sprite-kit feel free to contact me.

Comment: Well, iam still working on it,if something goes wrong I will contact you, but thanks for your help, @Felipe Cesar Assis